# Sort to get the list of elements in first place , list of ones in 2nd place etc

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Have a small dataframe (one group in a groupby, but not really relevant to this question), which looks something like this after sorting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], [1,2,2], [1,3,3]]).T
df.columns = ['name', 'sorter1', 'sorter2']
sorted_df = df.sort_values(['sorter1', 'sorter2'])
```

|  | name | sorter1 | sorter2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | b | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | c | 2 | 3 |

Want to transfer it into a dataframe of first, 2nd ad 3rd place,
Got this:

```
result = sorted_df[['name']].T
result.columns = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

|  | first | second | third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | a | b | c |

but what I really need is this:

|  | first | second | third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | a | ['b', 'c'] | nan |

any ideas, Pandas or other, are welcome, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Way:

```
df.sort_values(['sorter1', 'sorter2'], inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['sorter1', 'sorter2'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(list).reindex(df.index)[['name']].T
```

Comment: works fine, lacks the sorting though, the sort could be added before the groupby and force the groupby to not resort by adding sort=False flag to it